# What is behind "A. Grothendieck scheme theory" in Mondobrain?

Tags: bigdata, distance, methods

Mondobrain proposes a ["big data" technology](http://www.mondobrain.com/technology.html) with:

> a new generation of algorithms based on A. Grothendieck scheme theory
>   (Field Medal) that extract knowledge and rules from data without any
>   model or distance, and that can explore every part of 
>   multi-dimensional spaces independently.

What is behind this method that does not use "model of distance"? Are there relations methods like Topological Data Analysis (evoked at [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592421/why-does-topology-rarely-come-up-outside-of-topology/1592463#1592463))?

Comment: I'd ask them for a white paper. I can't imagine anybody would be willing to pay for their product without understanding how it works. The people behind TDA at Ayasdi have lots of papers. I have not encountered any research on scheme theory in machine learning.

Comment: I would also be interested in sharing any information on this Grothendieck scheme based approach as it seems quite original in the world of data science.
Any news from your side?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Emre I only got a vague paper, nothing solid to build on

Comment: Nothing solid yet, unfortunately